# Sort alphaNumeric HTML list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, sorting

I need to sort an alphaNumeric list. I am able to sort but some how because it is alphaNumeric, I am not able to put the abc1 before the abc10.

My HTML Code:

```
<ul class="theList">
   <li><b>abc11:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>abc10:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>xyz24:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>abc1:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>xyz2:</b>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

My JavaScript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
    list = document.getElementsByClassName("theList");
    for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
      switching = true;
      while (switching) {
        switching = false;
        b = list[j].getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
          shouldSwitch = false;
          if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
          b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
          switching = true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

My Result:

- abc10:Hello
- abc11:Hello
- abc1:Hello
- xyz24:Hello
- xyz2:Hello

Expected Result:

- abc1:Hello
- abc10:Hello
- abc11:Hello
- xyz2:Hello
- xyz24:Hello

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be a lot easier to sort the `li`s *in their own array*, outside of the document, and then append them to the `ul` again in the correct order. You can use `localeCompare` to check which string comes first lexicographically, no jQuery required:

```js
const theList = document.querySelector('.theList');
const lis = Array.from(theList.children);
const firstText = elm => elm.children[0].textContent;
lis.sort((a, b) => firstText(a).localeCompare(firstText(b)));
lis.forEach(li => theList.appendChild(li));
```

```html
<ul class="theList">
   <li><b>abc11:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>abc10:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>xyz24:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>abc1:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>xyz2:</b>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

To sort multiple such lists, iterate over a `querySelectorAll`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.theList').forEach((theList) => {
  const lis = Array.from(theList.children);
  const firstText = elm => elm.children[0].textContent;
  lis.sort((a, b) => firstText(a).localeCompare(firstText(b)));
  lis.forEach(li => theList.appendChild(li));
});
```

```html
<ul class="theList">
   <li><b>abc11:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>abc10:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>xyz24:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>abc1:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>xyz2:</b>Hello</li>
</ul>

<ul class="theList">
   <li><b>abc11:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>abc10:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>xyz24:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>abc1:</b>Hello</li>
   <li><b>xyz2:</b>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this works great but, I have multiple such lists with the same class name. This one only sorts the first list.

Comment: See edit, use `querySelectorAll` instead and iterate

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you! I am trying to use the logic above for just one `select` element. I seem to be getting an error. I would've thought the logic behind it is the same.

Comment: I just noticed a sorting issue and was hoping you can help me with it. When I run your code, I do get the values sorted. But incase I add a `abc2` to the list. It sorts it like this: `abc1, abc10, abc11, abc2`. Is there any ways for me to get it like `abc1, abc2, abc10, abc11`

Comment: Pass another argument to `localeCompare`: `'en-u-kn-true'` and it will compare the numbers as numbers rather than lexiographically.

Comment: I added it like so: `lis.sort((a, b) => firstText(a).localeCompare(firstText(b)), 'en-u-kn-true');` It didnt do anything to my list. Is what I did correct?

Comment: No, you're not passing it as an argument to `localeCompare`, you're passing it as another argument to `.sort`. Pass it to `localeCompare` instead.

Comment: Another option is for the second argument to `localeCompare` to be `undefined` and pass a third argument: `{ numeric: true }`

Comment: I don't understand the syntax, I thought I was passing it as an argument to `localeCompare`

Comment: You have `localeCompare(firstText(b))`, which means you're passing `localeCompare` one argument, the result of calling `firstText`. Put another argument inside the argument list for `localeCompare`.